# Split the string into two equal halves

Tags: javascript, php

```
$string="p1234,p12,p12345,1234,12,12345,12,45678,334,q1255,q67889,q235";
```

I want to split the string into two parts, but splitting can be done at the last occurrence of character "p" i.e after p12345
i would get as given below in to groups

```
$str1=p1234,p12,p12345;
$str2=1234,12,12345;
 $str3=q1255,q67889,q235;
```

Comment: You know your string's aren't the same length?!

Comment: When you say "equal halves", do you mean equal number of comma delimited components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string="p1234,p12,p12345,1234,12,12345";

$a = explode(',', $string);

$s1 = implode(',', array_slice($a, 0, count($a)/2))
$s2 = implode(',', array_slice($a, count($a)/2))

echo $s1
//⇒ p1234,p12,p12345
echo $s2
//⇒ 1234,12,12345
```

**UPD** The question was restated. Here goes the answer for p/non-p:

```
$a = explode(',', $string);

$s1 = implode(',', array_filter($a, function($e) { return $e[0] === 'p'; }))
$s2 = implode(',', array_filter($a, function($e) { return $e[0] !== 'p'; }))

echo $s1
//⇒ p1234,p12,p12345
echo $s2
//⇒ 1234,12,12345
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer to the question... There is no lookup to the last `p`-value...

Comment: @RichardBernards I am not sure I understand what do you mean.

Comment: You are just splitting the array in two parts of equal length... The `p` asked in the question is not taken into account anymore...

Comment: @RichardBernards Oh... The p-requirement appeared after I have this question answered. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$string = "p1234,p12,p12345,1234,12,12345";
$parts  = explode(',', $string);
$size   = count($parts);

$firsthalf  = implode(',', array_slice($parts, 0, $size / 2));
$secondhalf = implode(',', array_slice($parts, $size / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Will cut last occurrence of **p**

```
$string="p1234,p12,p12345,1234,12,12345";
$x = explode(',', $string);
$count=0;
foreach($x as $v) {
  if(strpos($v,'p') !== false) {
    $count++;
  }
}
echo $firsthalf  = implode(',', array_slice($x, $count)).'<br>';
echo $secondhalf = implode(',', array_slice($x, 0, $count));
```

Comment: I want to split the string at the last occurrence of character "p" i.e after p12345

Comment: avoid multibyte unsafe commands, i'd say.
Also, explode() and consecutive implode() are comparably complex internally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string="p1234,p12,p12345,1234,12,12345";
$x = explode(',', $string);
$x = array_chunk($x, count($x)/2);
$str1 = implode($x[0],',');
$str2 = implode($x[1],',');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy solution:**
Use [mb_strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strrpos.php) to find the last 'p'.
Then, use the resulting position as *offset* when
using [mb_strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) for search the first comma after it.
Use [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) to get the two parts.
Done.
! Mind the difference: mb_str**r**pos() vs. mb_strpos() !

**Elegant solution:**
If you want to split really at the first combination of [comma][cipher],
as would match your example, you can also just issue one [mb_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).
Then you just have to use the right regular expression for [comma][cipher], which i won't elaborate for you here.

Comment: (Not claiming that regular expressions are comparably less complex ;D )